# Xcode iOS framework icon meanings

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

When using Xcode 7.3 to add an iOS Framework to an iOS project (General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries), Xcode uses two different icons to represent iOS frameworks. One looks like a white cube and the other looks like a toolbox. What do each of these icons mean?

[image: xcode]

Answer (score 7):

The toolbox icon represents a framework that uses Foundation.  The white cube (lego piece) represents any bundle that links against the Cocoa/Cocoa Touch frameworks.

Comment: I have noticed that the icons for the same framework may change if I drag them from one project to another. For instance a toolbox may change to a white cube.

Comment: an extension of this question--what is the significance of whether or not these icons have a black shadow behind them? eg a white cube will sometimes get a shadow behind it, sometimes not

Comment: Is there a reference for these and other icons?

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks are bundles that contain a linkable library (usually a dylib) and the associated resources and headers for development.

There are “public” and “private” frameworks. The former are usually well documented and prepared for use by general developers, while the latter are (supposed to be) restricted for internal use only.

The original libraries are no longer useful for non-on-device-developers, so they are eliminated from the system. The framework folders still contain other resources, such as localization strings.

Frameworks have an extension of .framework. Headers, if any, are stored in a subdirectory called Headers. **This should be yellow tool box.** . This is support for iOS devices and simulators.

**The white cube box represents resource bundle** for targets.

The magic for getting the resources to play nicely is to put all the resources in to a bundle which we'll include from the other projects .

So we need to add a targets to the library project of the type **Bundle**

When the resources bundle targets is added it will default to being set up with a Mac OS X build target. But if you want to IOS one so you just need to change the relevant settings.

Refer the link for bundle create 
http://jaym2503.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-create-resource-bundle-in-ios.html