# Why even native frameworks are showing as white box instead of yellow toolbox in my xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, uikit

I yesterday downloaded Xcode 12.2 and created a new sample project. In that project i added a native framework UIKit.framework but it appears to me as a white box instead of normal yellow toolbox. I definitely had a research in SO before posting my question but i found that they have this problem with custom frameworks but in my case even native frameworks are being shown as white box. The links which i researched are

- [Why are some linked frameworks look like a piece of Lego, while others like a toolbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38197461/14621362)

  [Xcode iOS framework icon meanings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37009266/14621362)

I have used xcode 13 but in that i have no such problems. **Can anyone tell what is the real reason behind this?** Is it something specific problem related to Xcode 12.2 version?

[image: Issue Image]

Comment: Is this affecting your project in some way? i.e., are you asking because this is a symptom of some problem, or because you're curious about why Xcode might be showing this icon?

Comment: just curious about why Xcode might be showing this icon